# How to combine async and non-async options in Axios GET request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios, token

I currently have a correctly working async get request like this:

```
export async function _default_options() {
  return {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": await getAuthToken(),
    },
  };
}

export const get = async function(url: string, _options: any) {
  const options = _options || await _default_options();
  return axios.get(url, options);
};
```

A typical use of calling this GET function (which resides in requests.js) would be this:

```
requests.get(`${requests.API_ROOT()}acct_mgmt/users`)
```

You can see that because no `options` are passed in that it picks up `_default_options` and all works fine.

But now I wish to introduce an Axios Cancel token into the mix:

```
const signal = axios.CancelToken.source(); 
requests.get(`${requests.API_ROOT()}account_management/companies`, { cancelToken: signal.token })
```

Clearly I can't use the code above because then the `cancelToken` just replaces the Auth token, which won't work.  So I need to combine them.  But the async nature of `_default_options` is throwing me for a loop.

How would you approach this issue of combining a Cancel token and an Auth token?

Robert

Answer (score 0):

I believe passing options in and spreading them over the defaults should work, like so:

```
export async function _default_options(overrides:any={}) {
  return {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": await getAuthToken(),
    },
    ...overrides,
  };
}

export const get = async function(url: string, _options: any) {
  const options = await _default_options(_options);
  return axios.get(url, options);
};
```